# How can an Object stand on an animated Platform

Tags: c#, animation, 2d, unity-game-engine

I have a Platform animated with Unity and if a Character jumps on the Platform (it is animated to move from left to right...), the Character stands still and because the Platform moves the Character falls out of the world.

**I want to have it like in a Super Mario Game that my Character moves with the Platform.**

Some Information:
2D Game, like Super Mario Bros
Script : C#
Program: Unity 5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try parenting the player with the platform by using [transform.parent](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html) and then check if the player is parented and move it by its local position using [transform.localPosition](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html)

Comment: how to remove the parent ??

Comment: try transform.parent = null;

Answer (score 1):

aligning your character to a moving platform can always be a tricky process, especially if you're using the built in physics with Unity3D.

[Here's an answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/8207/charactercontroller-falls-through-or-slips-off-mov.html) that I found on the unity forums, with a good discussion about having a character controller move with floating platforms. I hope this helps.